# Как отловить exception если он обработан внутри и не пробрасывается? (Java)

Tags: java, исключения

Суть проблемы следующая:

Есть класс, с большим количеством разных методов, с большим количеством вложенностей (которые тоже полны методов). Многие из них могут вызвать *эксепшены*. *Эксепшены* не пробрасываются, почти всегда обрабатываются на месте (выше обозначенного класса практически ни один не выбрасывает).

Как с минимальным вмешательством в код выловить информацию о всех *исключениях* (вместе со стеком)? 
Возможно обернуть в другой класс? Если да, то как сделать что бы гарантированно я мог узнать о всех *эксепшенах*?

Comment: Я только вижу решение с проброской исключений.

Comment: Возможно, там логика построена на эксепшинах. И если их попытаться пробросить - можно порушить логику работу кода в целом.

Я бы попытался подменить базовый класс исключений и заставить его логировать (или отсылать по tcp/udp).

Comment: Не совсем подходит вариант с подменой базового класса: логировать все без исключения эксепшены мне нет необходимости (даже более того это сильно будет мешать), а только лишь у некоторых классов (и их графов), которые я бы хотел заранее определить. Поэтому я и предположил вариант с оберткой. Или отдельной функцией которую вызывать в процессе.

Comment: тогда нужно делать что-то вида отладчика.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если нет возможности изменить исходный код или это очень сложно, то можно использовать модификацию байткода (bytecode instrumentation).

Например с помощью библиотеки [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) и метода [MethodVisitor.visitTryCatchBlock](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitTryCatchBlock%28org.objectweb.asm.Label,%20org.objectweb.asm.Label,%20org.objectweb.asm.Label,%20java.lang.String%29) найти все блоки `try\catch` и модифицировать их таким образом, чтобы все исключения перед обработкой сохранялись в некоторую структуру данных или выводились в лог.

Comment: Вопрос: а в таком случае возможно выборочно модифицировать? Например применить этот метод только для класса и графа его вложенных классов.

Comment: @Juister Да, конечно.